# Sklearn.KMeans : how to avoid Memory or Value Error?

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm working on an image classification problem and I'm creating a bag of words model. To do that, I extracted the SIFT descriptors of all my images and I have to use the KMeans algorithm to find the centers to use as my bag of words.

Here is the data I have:

- Number of images: 1584
- Number of SIFT descriptors (vector of 32 elements): 571685
- Number of center: 15840

So I ran a KMeans algorithm to compute my centers:

```
dico = pickle.load(open('./dico.bin', 'rb')) # np.shape(dico) = (571685, 32)
k = np.size(os.listdir(img_path)) * 10 # = 1584 * 10

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, n_init=1, verbose=1).fit(dico)

pickle.dump(kmeans, open('./kmeans.bin', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(kmeans.cluster_centers_, open('./dico_reduit.bin', 'wb'))
```

With this code, I got a Memory Error because I don't have enough memory on my laptop (only 2GB) so I decided to divide by 2 the number of center and to choose randomly half of my SIFT descriptors. This time, I got `Value Error : array is too big`.

What can I do to get a relevant result without memory problem?

Comment: Show the shape of ```dico```. (as i'm a bit confused by the numbers in your post; but i don't have experiece with bag-of-word models)

Comment: I add the information in the code. It's useless to understand how works bag-of-word model, it's just for context.

Comment: Okay. So the dominating dimension is the sample-dimension (and not feature-dimension). This means, you can use some online-kmeans, like [MiniBatchKMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html). Instead of reading everything into memory, only ```n=batch_size``` will be within memory in each iteration.

Comment: That exactly what I need. You can add an answer if you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @sascha said in this comment, I just have to use [MiniBatchKMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) class to avoid this problem:

```py
dico = pickle.load(open('./dico.bin', 'rb'))

batch_size = np.size(os.listdir(img_path)) * 3
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1).fit(dico)

pickle.dump(kmeans, open('./minibatchkmeans.bin', 'wb'))
```

Comment: And how do you set batch size?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Using `batch_size` argument

Comment: How do you decide?

Comment: @NicolasGervais This is discussed in this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398757/how-to-determine-the-best-batch-size-value-for-mini-batch-k-means-algorithm Apparently, there is no magic solution and you will have to iterate to find the best value.