# Python sklearn ValueError: array is too big

Tags: python, scikit-learn, geospatial

I made simple script on Python (ver.3.7) that classifies satellite image, but It can classify only clip of the satellite image. When I'm trying to classify the whole satellite image, it returns this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v0-3.py", line 219, in classification_tool
  File "sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 972, in fit
  File "sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 312, in k_means
  File "sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 496, in check_array
  File "numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

I tried using MiniBatchKMeans instead of KMeans (from [Sklearn.KMeans : how to avoid Memory or Value Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632456/sklearn-kmeans-how-to-avoid-memory-or-value-error)), but It still doesn't work. How I can avoid or solve this error? Maybe there are some mistakes in my code?

Comment: What is resolution of images?

Comment: cols 8151, rows 7381

Comment: How about to reduce it to `82 * 74`?

Comment: how can I reduce it?

Comment: Preprocess all of your images? I think it is too big...

Comment: Can you tell me please what exactly I need to do?

Comment: How did you normalize your image data? You might make them in the same resolution, right? Or check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images-via-command-line and reasonably resize your images. `8151 * 7381` is more than 60M. If an image is rgb/rgba, your `array` contains more than 180/240M `float`s...

Comment: this kind of image isn't that simple, I guess. GTiff image contains 7 bands of satellite image and weighs about 400 megabyte but I'll try to resize it or preprocess. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh I'm idiot because I used x32 version of Python instead of x64. 
Maybe reinstalling Python to x64 version will solve your problem, user